# Twitter API & facebook connection problem

Tags: facebook, twitter

Is there any problem on Twitter API?
I installed twitter API on my fanpage, and I tried to feed my tweet on the wall.
It is OK to feed on my Profile, but cannot to feed on the wall.

What I did is 
install twitter API
set my twitter account
after I confirmed it shows "Facebook & Twitter accounts are connected!" on the page
I clicked on the check box of both Facebook Profile and Facebook Page at App permissions

After these operation, I reloaded the page.
It remains as checked on "Facebook Profile" but disappeared from check box of "Facebook Page".

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never really set up Twitter for my Facebook Account, but when the official tool doesn't work properly i would suggest you to use the "Notes" Application on Facebook to feed an RSS feed to your wall. Twitter gives every not locked Twitter Account an RSS Feed which contains it's tweet and one for the Tweets the User favorites.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Appreciate for your advice I would try it. Thanks a lot!